# Select all checkbox option works only once, then nothing

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a bunch of checkboxes and I'm trying to get a de/select all button working for them. The checkboxes are set be images via labels and are inside an expandable div using jquery slidetoggle, and I'm using bootstrap, not sure if that matters.

Also the checkboxes themselves are made via a php loop as theres around 30 things I'd rather keep it this way and not have to do each one individually, plus it means I can just add new ones to database and it works. I'm saying this, as I feel this php loop might be the issue.

My current code structure, including the scripts for the checkboxes and expand div is as follows:

```
<script> 
          $(document).ready(function(){          
            $(".fliplogo").click(function(){       
            $(".panellogo").slideToggle("slow"); 
            });
          });
        </script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name="all"],input[name="title"]').bind('click', function(){
        var status = $(this).is(':checked');
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', $(this).parent('li')).attr('checked', status);
        });
        });
        </script>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse fliplogo" style="padding:5px; color:white">
        Car Manufacture

        </div>

          <div id="sites" class="navbar navbar-inverse panellogo" style="display:none; min-height:0px"> 
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" style="color:white" checked/> 
                <label for='all' style="color:white">Select All Manufactures
              </label><br>

            <?php
              $webserver = 'localhost'; 
              $administrator = 'root';
              $password = '';
              $db_name = 'cdb';
              $db = mysqli_connect($webserver, $administrator, $password, $db_name)
                or die('Error connecting');

              $query = "SELECT DISTINCT make,logo FROM cars";
              $result = mysqli_query($db, $query)
                or die("Error in query: '$query'");
              $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
              $i = 0;
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                $i++; 

                echo'                    
                    <input type="checkbox" style="display:none" id="'.$i.'" value="'.$row['make'].'" checked/>
                      <label for="'.$i.'"><img src="'.$row['logo'].'" style="height:50px; width:50px"/>
                    </label>
                    ';
                }
            ?>
            </li>
          </div>
```

And css:

```
.input_hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

#sites label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#sites label:hover {
    background-color: #500000;
}

#sites label img {
    padding: 3px;    
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

This Fiddle shows the select all code I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/H37cb/433/

and this Fiddle for the checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgh24/1171/

Even if I try it all on its own on my site just with the code from the all checkbox fiddle it acts the same. No matter where I place the code from the fiddle it acts the same, works once, then stops.
The check/uncheck button will work once then stops. If they are all selected at the start it will unselect them, they're it will select then unseelct... and thats it.

All help very appreciated -Tom

Comment: works fine for me....can check/uncheck all as many times as I want.

Comment: @bryan No matter where I place the code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/H37cb/433/ its acts the same, on its own as basic checkboxes, it'll work once then stop.

Comment: maybe I'm confused, but I can click all as many times as I want and it selects/unselects all... not sure what the problem is.